# Laravel (5.6) Eloquent Relationship for Ecommerce

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So, I am trying to think through Laravel Eloquent Relationships for an Ecommerce project I'm working on.  I have a products table and I'm thinking about creating a flavors table and a sizes table.  Here are the relationships I'm looking at:

One product can have many flavors - this one I can just use the one-to-many, i.e. hasMany, relationship.

One product can have many sizes - this one I can just use the one-to-many, i.e. hasMany, relationship.

One flavor can be associated with many products - this one I'm not sure about because I don't want to just recreate a flavor in the flavors table and associate the repeated flavor with a different product, I'd like to associate the flavor with many products, but not sure how to accomplish this.  Suggestions?

Or does someone have a clean(er) way of accomplishing this?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can save flavour's ID in products table (if product only have ONE flavour).

To save more than one flavour in a product, you need a third table.

**Example:**

TableProducts | TableFlavours | TableUsedFlavours (will hold Product's ID and Flavour's ID).

Than search product using "with" to relationship TableUsedFlavours. With relationships you can relate TableFlavours as well, to bring flavour's name.

Retrieving Flavour's from a product (with flavour's name as well):

Products controller do eloquent query:

```
$record: Product::select(some_fields)
->with('flavours')
->get();
```

Products modal, create the 'flavours' function:

```
public function flavours()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UsedFlavours::class, 'product_id', 'id')
                    ->with(['flavour' =>function($query){
        $query->select(['flavour_name'])->where(anything);}]);
    }
```

Now in UsedFlavours model:

```
public function feature(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Flavour::class,'flavour_id','id');
    }
```

Now in Flavour model:

```
public function usedFeatures()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('UsedFlavours','id');
    }
```

This code is not tested, but that's the logic.

Comment: Okay, so I'm trying to understand.  The third table is still a one-to-one relationship, yes?  How does that allow me to relate one flavor to many products?

Comment: Okay, I sort of get what you're saying and I'm going to try to implement.  I'll come back if I have any more questions.  Thank you!